# SupportMapFragment appearing blank (Map Google V2)

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2, supportmapfragment

I want to load a `SupportMapFragment` in a `Fragment` container. I get no errors, my API Key is fine, Google Play Services Library is imported and all permissions are called.

I call the `MapFragment` this way:

```
MapaFragment fragment = new MapaFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft2.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment)          
    .commit();
```

The `Fragment` is as follows:

```
public class MapaFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
private View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa, null);

    return v;       
}
```

And the layout for the map is as simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapa"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: I have the same problem only when load the application for the firs time AND without internet connection. Is it something expected to happen?

Comment: In my case I checked Google Maps API V2 instead of Google Maps ANDROID API V2.... Double check it.

Comment: I checked it. Nothing! I have the right one checked! Google Maps Android API V2. Do I have to turn on internet connection for the first time user opens the map?

Comment: @indi how exactly you check between those two? Where can I find this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already added SupportMapFragment in xml layout file, it's not necessary to add it again in code or override onCreateView method, just comment out these

```
MapaFragment fragment = new MapaFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft2.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment)          
    .commit();
```

and these

```
private View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa, null);

    return v;       
}
```

lines of code and try to run the app

Comment: Ok thanks but if I comment the first block... how will the app load the map??

Comment: you have already added SupportMapFragment in your xml layout, it's enough, and if you want to create custom map fragment put your class name (com.abc.custommap) in xml (last line in example: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment")

Comment: Mmm, ok I'll try both options (usual and custom class). Anyway, I'm calling MapaFragment from another Fragment so I understand FragmentTransaction keeps being absolutely necessary.

Comment: When you add MapFragment in activity's layout file, it's automatically attaches to the activity, all you have to do it retrieve this fragment using findFragmentById, for example: MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)

Comment: Well thanks to you and Analyzer I realised the onCreateView for MapaFragment is never called... Please give me some light... I mean, I commented it and everything works like before: does not. I also checked with Log this method never gets called...

Comment: OMG.... I checked Google Maps API V2 instead of Google Maps ANDROID API V2.... Well, to whom it may serve. Thanks Vladimir.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure, your API key is fine?
Please try this function to check in your activity's onCreate method:

```
 private void getShaKey() {

 try {
 PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
 PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
 for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
 md.update(signature.toByteArray());
 Log.v(TAG, "KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
 Base64.DEFAULT));
 }
 } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
```

And see, if it returns the same, as which you put into your manifest:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

Then please check, if getMap() is not returning null like this:

```
GoogleMap myMap;

myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa)).getMap();

if(myMap != null){
...
}
```

You can do this in your onCreateView method before the "return v" statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try and let you know as soon as I can.. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm stuck, the API_KEY returned by your function is completely different to the API_KEY created with the debug_keystore for this app. What does it mean? Tanks in advance

Comment: @Analizer The API_KEY in the manifest is for production purposes only.  It does not have to be replaced with a debug api key.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Are you sure? Than how can you see and test the map when writing code using debug keystore?

Comment: You need to go to the Google API Console and put your SHA1 key from your machine in order for Google to authenticate you in debug mode.  The section is called API Access -> Edit allowed Android apps...

Comment: I know that, but why couldn't you register your debug key as well as your production key?