# Google Maps Fragment, not blank, markers there but no actual map displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem loading a map.

[I am attempting this tutorial on Vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#googlemaps_project)

1. I initially had a problem with my SHA1 from the debug.keystore. I used this value to generate an API key that would only produce a completely blank map.
2. I followed the advice of @Analizer on this post: [stackoverflow.com/questions/15607295/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607295/supportmapfragment-appearing-blank-map-google-v2) and produced a totally different API which I copied into my manifest.

Now I get the following map, the markers from the tutorial are shown, but no actual map?

[Click for image (I don't have a reputation of 10 yet so cannot directly post them!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryDbg.jpg)

Can anyone advise?

Edit: I should mention **I am using IntelliJ IDEA**

Edit: In case anyone has the same issue, the method in point 1. of my original question was the correct answer, I had to wait approx 1hr between generating the key and seeing a map!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this through google, the method in point 1. of my original question was the correct answer, I had to wait approx 1hr between generating the key and seeing a map!

Answer (score 0):

use SHA1 from the eclipse :

Windows -> preferences -> Android -> Build

and then generate new api key and use it to display map.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA, I will update the question to include this!

Comment: can you please print the log here?

Comment: What would you like me to post? The app does not crash so I don't have a sensible error log.

Comment: Ignore that, I have a map! I guess I was being impatient with the Google server updating!